# Error in prcomp.default(data, scale = FALSE, center = FALSE) : cannot rescale a constant/zero column to unit variance

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

my data set hast got 821049 rows and 18 columns. It is about shopping cart abandonment. My task is to cluster shopping cart abandonments. Therefore I used the command subset to display only the lines of the users with a dropout (WKA ==1). Then I tried to execute K-Means and visualize the results graphically. Here an error occurred. I wonder if the error has to do with the variance of some of the variables. There are variables with a low variance for example 0.01, 0.06.

```
WKA_ohneJB <- read.csv("WKA_ohneJB_PCA.csv", header=TRUE, sep = ";")

WKA <- subset(WKA_ohneJB, WKA == 1)

set.seed (123)

sample <- WKA  [sample(nrow(WKA), 10000), ]

fviz_nbclust(sample, kmeans, method = "wss")+ geom_vline(xintercept = 4, linetype = 2)

set.seed(123) 

km.res <- kmeans(sample, 3, nstart = 40)

print(km.res)

fviz_cluster(km.res, data = sample, scale = T, palette = c("#2E9FDF",   "#00AFBB", "#E7B800"), ellipse.type = "jaccard",
         star.plot = TRUE,
         repel = TRUE, ggtheme = theme_minimal() )



structure(list(X = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 9L, 11L, 15L, 16L, 
821037L, 821038L, 821039L, 821040L, 821041L, 821042L, 821043L, 
821044L, 821047L, 821048L), BASKETS_NZ = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
LOGONS = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), PIS = c(71L, 39L, 50L, 4L, 
13L, 4L, 13L, 23L, 8L, 7L, 24L, 3L, 111L, 33L, 3L, 46L, 11L, 
8L, 65L, 15L), PIS_AP = c(14L, 2L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 13L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L), PIS_DV = c(3L, 
19L, 4L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 38L, 8L, 0L, 
5L, 2L, 0L, 3L, 2L), PIS_PL = c(0L, 5L, 8L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
11L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 32L, 8L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L), PIS_SDV = c(18L, 
0L, 11L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 
13L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), PIS_SHOPS = c(3L, 24L, 13L, 3L, 0L, 
0L, 2L, 17L, 0L, 0L, 7L, 1L, 71L, 16L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 0L, 3L, 
2L), PIS_SR = c(19L, 0L, 14L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
11L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 20L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), QUANTITY = c(13L, 
2L, 18L, 1L, 14L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 
4L, 1L, 3L, 17L, 8L), WKA = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), NEW_CUST = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), EXIST_CUST = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), WEB_CUST = c(1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), MOBILE_CUST = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), 
TABLET_CUST = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L), LOGON_CUST_STEP2 = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 9L, 
11L, 15L, 16L, 821037L, 821038L, 821039L, 821040L, 821041L, 821042L, 
821043L, 821044L, 821047L, 821048L), class = "data.frame")
```

> Error in prcomp.default(data, scale = FALSE, center = FALSE) : 
>     cannot rescale a constant/zero column to unit variance

Comment: the problem comes from scale = TRUE, because you sampled first, and if that column has a lot of zeros, when it gets to this step.. it throws an error

Comment: @StupidWolf I removed scale = T and then I tried it with scale = F but the error is the same.